# How to make tf.data.Dataset.from_generator yield batches with a custom generator

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I want to use the `tf.data` API. My expected workflow looks like the following:

- Input image is a 5D tensor  with `(batch_size, width, height,
  channels, frames)`
- First layer is a 3D convolution

I use the `tf.data.from_generator` function to create an iterator. Later I make a initializable iterator.

My code would look something like this:

```
def custom_gen():
   img = np.random.normal((width, height, channels, frames))
   yield(img, img) # I train an autoencoder, so the x == y`

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.batch(batch_size).from_generator(custom_generator)
iter = dataset.make_initializable_iterator()

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(iter.get_next())
```

I would expect that `iter.get_next()` yielded me a 5D tensor with the batch size. However, I even tried to yield the batch size in my own `custom_generator` and it does not work. I face an error, when I want to initialize the dataset with my placeholder of the input shape `(batch_size, width, height, channels, frames)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Dataset` construction process in that example is ill-formed. It should be done in this order, as also established by the official guide on [Importing Data](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/datasets):

1. A base dataset creation function or static method should be called for establishing the original **source** of data (e.g. the static methods `from_slice_tensors`, `from_generator`, `list_files`, ...).
2. At this point, **transformations** may be applied by chaining adapter methods (such as `batch`).

Thus, in TensorFlow 2.9:

```py
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(
     generator,
     output_signature=(
         tf.TensorSpec(shape=(width, height, channels, frames), dtype=tf.float32),
         tf.TensorSpec(shape=(width, height, channels, frames), dtype=tf.float32)
    ).batch(batch_size)
```

In TensorFlow 1:

```py
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(custom_generator).batch(batch_size)
```

Comment: this answer is no longer valid, as `from_generator` now requires either `output_types` or `output_signature` (but in reality, it wants the `output_types`)

Comment: @Mahrkeenerh "but in reality, it wants the `output_types`". The documentation of the currently latest version (2.9.1) states that `output_types` (and `output_shapes`) is deprecated and should be replaced with `output_signature`, as they will be removed in a future version.